# Parsing binary file too slow in C++ using memory-mapped files

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-mapped-files, micro-optimization

I'm trying to parse a binary file integer-wise in order to check whether the integer value fulfills a certain condition but the loop is very slow.

Furthermore, I found that `memory-mapped file`s are the fastest for reading a file into the memory quickly, hence I'm using the following [`Boost`](https://www.boost.org)-based code:

```
unsigned long long int get_file_size(const char *file_path) {
    const filesystem::path file{file_path};
    const auto generic_path = file.generic_path();
    return filesystem::file_size(generic_path);
}

boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source read_bytes(const char *file_path,
                                         const unsigned long long int offset,
                                         const unsigned long long int length) {
    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_params parameters;
    parameters.path = file_path;
    parameters.length = static_cast<size_t>(length);
    parameters.flags = boost::iostreams::mapped_file::mapmode::readonly;
    parameters.offset = static_cast<boost::iostreams::stream_offset>(offset);

    boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source file;

    file.open(parameters);
    return file;
}

boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source read_bytes(const char *file_path) {
    const auto file_size = get_file_size(file_path);
    const auto mapped_file_source = read_bytes(file_path, 0, file_size);
    return mapped_file_source;
}
```

My test case roughly looks as follows:

```
inline auto test_parsing_binary_file_performance() {
    const auto start_time = get_time();
    const std::filesystem::path input_file_path = "...";
    const auto mapped_file_source = read_bytes(input_file_path.string().c_str());
    const auto file_buffer = mapped_file_source.data();
    const auto file_buffer_size = mapped_file_source.size();
    LOG_S(INFO) << "File buffer size: " << file_buffer_size;
    auto printed_lap = (long) (file_buffer_size / (double) 1000);
    printed_lap = round_to_nearest_multiple(printed_lap, sizeof(int));
    LOG_S(INFO) << "Printed lap: " << printed_lap;
    std::vector<int> values;
    values.reserve(file_buffer_size / sizeof(int)); // Pre-allocate a large enough vector
    // Iterate over every integer
    for (auto file_buffer_index = 0; file_buffer_index < file_buffer_size; file_buffer_index += sizeof(int)) {
        const auto value = *(int *) &file_buffer[file_buffer_index];
        if (value >= 0x30000000 && value < 0x49000000 - sizeof(int) + 1) {
            values.push_back(value);
        }

        if (file_buffer_index % printed_lap == 0) {
            LOG_S(INFO) << std::setprecision(4) << file_buffer_index / (double) file_buffer_size * 100 << "%";
        }
    }

    LOG_S(INFO) << "Values found count: " << values.size();

    print_time_taken(start_time, false, "Parsing binary file");
}
```

The `memory-mapped file` reading finishes almost instantly as expected but iterating it integer-wise is way too slow on my machine despite excellent hardware (`SSD` etc.):

```
2020-12-20 13:04:35.124 (   0.019s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:387   INFO| File buffer size: 419430400
2020-12-20 13:04:35.124 (   0.019s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:390   INFO| Printed lap: 419432
2020-12-20 13:04:35.135 (   0.029s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 0%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.171 (   0.065s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 0.1%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.196 (   0.091s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 0.2%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.216 (   0.111s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 0.3%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.241 (   0.136s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 0.4%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.272 (   0.167s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 0.5%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.293 (   0.188s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 0.6%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.314 (   0.209s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 0.7%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.343 (   0.237s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 0.8%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.366 (   0.261s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 0.9%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.399 (   0.293s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 1%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.421 (   0.315s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 1.1%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.447 (   0.341s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 1.2%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.468 (   0.362s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 1.3%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.487 (   0.382s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 1.4%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.520 (   0.414s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 1.5%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.540 (   0.435s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 1.6%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.564 (   0.458s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 1.7%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.586 (   0.480s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 1.8%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.608 (   0.503s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 1.9%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.636 (   0.531s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 2%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.658 (   0.552s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 2.1%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.679 (   0.574s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 2.2%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.702 (   0.597s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 2.3%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.727 (   0.622s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 2.4%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.769 (   0.664s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 2.5%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.802 (   0.697s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 2.6%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.831 (   0.726s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 2.7%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.860 (   0.754s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 2.8%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.887 (   0.781s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 2.9%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.924 (   0.818s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 3%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.956 (   0.850s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 3.1%
2020-12-20 13:04:35.998 (   0.893s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 3.2%
2020-12-20 13:04:36.033 (   0.928s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 3.3%
2020-12-20 13:04:36.060 (   0.955s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 3.4%
2020-12-20 13:04:36.102 (   0.997s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 3.5%
2020-12-20 13:04:36.132 (   1.026s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:405   INFO| 3.6%
...
2020-12-20 13:05:03.456 (  28.351s) [main thread     ]Tests.hpp:410   INFO| Values found count: 10650389
2020-12-20 13:05:03.456 (  28.351s) [main thread     ]          benchmark.cpp:31    INFO| Parsing binary file took 28.341 second(s)
```

Parsing those `419 MB` always takes around 28 - 70 seconds. Even compiling in `Release` mode does not really help. Is there any way to cut this time down? It doesn't seem like the operation I'm performing should be that inefficient.

Note that I'm compiling for `Linux 64-bit` using `GCC 10`.

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments, using `memory-mapped file`s with `advise()` also does not help the performance:

```
boost::interprocess::file_mapping file_mapping(input_file_path.string().data(), boost::interprocess::read_only);
boost::interprocess::mapped_region mapped_region(file_mapping, boost::interprocess::read_only);
mapped_region.advise(boost::interprocess::mapped_region::advice_sequential);
const auto file_buffer = (char *) mapped_region.get_address();
const auto file_buffer_size = mapped_region.get_size();
...
```

Lessons learned so far by taking into account the comments/answers:

- Using `advise(boost::interprocess::mapped_region::advice_sequential)` does not help
- Not calling `reserve()` or calling it with exactly the right size **can double the performance**
- Iterating directly on `int *` is a bit slower than iterating on a `char *`
- Using a `std::set` is a bit slower than a `std::vector` for collecting the results
- The progress logging is insignificant for the performance

Comment: `*(int *)` is UB (strict aliasing violation). Also where are the `%` log lines? Please include the first few. Does adding `file.advise(boost::interprocess::mapped_region::advice_sequential);` help?

Comment: @rustyx: I tried the `memory-mapped file` approach with `advise()` and it didn't improve the performance. Also I added some of the missing log lines.

Comment: just to be sure... Copying the file to /dev/null how much time does it take? ah... and "The memory-mapped file reading finishes almost instantly as expected" doesn't make much sense. If linux memory mapping works like in other OS, the file isn't read on opening... Each time you try to read a block of 4kb (a memory page), there is a fault that is catched by the OS and the page is filled from disk.

Comment: @xanatos: Copying the file takes about `4 seconds` and thank you about the hint that `memory-mapped file`s cause multiple disk accesses. I replaced that code with reading the entire file into memory before processing it and it solved the performance problem by cutting down the processing time by a lot.

Comment: Another example showing that with I/O bound problems I/O is the limiting performance factor. I wonder how much performance improves if you do an unbuffered [read](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) instead of using iostreams. There is probably some potential doing raw disk I/O by writing and reading directly to a dedicated partition reserved for that purpose (like read from /dev/sda2 or such). Whether that makes sense in a workflow depends on how you obtain your data. If it is generated locally you may not go through the disk at all. If it is obtained via LAN, likewise.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by [`xanatos`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613130/xanatos) `memory-mapped file`s are deceiving in performance since they don't really read the entire file into memory in an instant. During processing, multiple disk accesses are caused on page misses, severely degrading the performance.

In this case it is more efficient to read the entire file into the memory first and then iterating through the memory:

```
inline std::vector<std::byte> load_file_into_memory(const std::filesystem::path &file_path) {
    std::ifstream input_stream(file_path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

    if (input_stream.fail()) {
        const auto error_message = "Opening " + file_path.string() + " failed";
        throw std::runtime_error(error_message);
    }

    auto current_read_position = input_stream.tellg();
    input_stream.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    auto file_size = std::size_t(current_read_position - input_stream.tellg());
    if (file_size == 0) {
        return {};
    }

    std::vector<std::byte> buffer(file_size);

    if (!input_stream.read((char *) buffer.data(), buffer.size())) {
        const auto error_message = "Reading from " + file_path.string() + " failed";
        throw std::runtime_error(error_message);
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Now the performance is much more acceptable with roughly `3 - 15 seconds` in total.

Comment: I'll say that it is a bad idea to read a whole file of indeterminate size in memory... This isn't the road I would ever suggest. Sadly I don't have a Linux machine here to debug why your read is slow. But you don't really to read the whole file. You can read the file in blocks of 4kb (or more... there is a diminishing return normally... The only important thing is to use 4kb multiples: 8kb, 16kb, 32kb, 64kb...)

Comment: You typically buffer your files, which is exactly what `std::ifstream` does. Have you tried just iterating over that?

Comment: @xanatos: Yes, I'm generally also offering a buffered version for the end user of the software in case it is needed (e.g. when the file(s) don't fully fit into the RAM). However, it would most likely be slower than reading it all at once.

Comment: I don't see why streaming the file (with a sufficiently large buffer, e.g. 1MB) should be significantly slower than reading it all into RAM at once, then iterating over it. Disk I/O is by far the slowest bottleneck in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of my first encounter with slowness, some 40 years ago. Caused by a percentage bar measuring the progress. Comment that part out and measure again.
Also measure the capacity reserve, and check the actual capacity neeeded - if it is 1% then you are wasting space and hence time.

- `unsigned long long` might be costly. Is not `unsignedlong` sufficient?
- Modulo, division might be extra costly.
- The progress logging might be slow, optimally a separate thread and then check
  whether flushing (contra-intuitively) might not be faster.

So:

```
const auto pct_factor = file_buffer_size == 0 ? 0.0 : 100 / (double)file_buffer_size;
values.reserve(file_buffer_size / sizeof(int));
for (auto file_buffer_index = 0, long pct_countdown = 0; file_buffer_index < file_buffer_size; file_buffer_index += sizeof(int)) {
    const auto value = *(int *) &file_buffer[file_buffer_index];
    if (value >= 0x30000000 && value < 0x49000000 - sizeof(int) + 1) {
        values.push_back(value);
    }

    if (pct_countdown-- < 0) {
        pct_countdown = printed_lap;
        const auto pct = file_buffer_index * pct_factor;
        LOG_S(INFO) << std::setprecision(4) << pct << "%";
    }
}
```

- Integer percentages would even be better. Discarding precision somewhat.
- The bulk data `values` - is it needed as such. A set could be sufficient.

I admit that I have my doubts on `*(int *)`. Using an `int*` pointer and increasing that seems more direct too.

Comment: The progress logging doesn't significantly impact the performance. Reserving exactly the right vector size in advance actually cuts time down in about half but leaving out the `reserve()` gives roughly the same benefit. Iterating directly with `int *` does not help (in fact it's even a bit slower again). Using a `std::set` seems to be slower as well. Still I end up with about `24 seconds` of processing time which doesn't seem optimal, yet.

Comment: `long long` and modulo are almost certainly - no definitely - not the problem here.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 thanks, though I hope it is indeed not the way memory mapped input is used.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza values.add happens conditionally, so `reserve` could be a huge waste. That the progress logging (and the code around it is not the culprit means that there might be memory problems.